# How to create HTML page with N number of div's initially

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm doing a page like a form with Multiple Steps.

But what before that I take a number N from a previous form which represents the number of steps of the form.

Each step needs a specific div of class "tab".
Now, I need to use Javascript or PHP to do this to duplicate the main div to N times.

```
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">

    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
    <div class="tab">
        <h1>Register:</h1>
        Name:
        <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: well then.. go for it and if you should face any problems, let us know.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your best attempt(code). Please read [ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can occupy a for and repeat the divs for the number of steps you bring with POST or GET

```
<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->

<?php 

    $divs = $_POST('number_divs'); 
    
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $divs; $i++) { 
    
?>

<div class="tab">
    <h1>Register:</h1>
    Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
</div> 

<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: English please! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code clones the div N times

```
<html>
<body>

    <div class="tab" id="id0">
        <p>Test Tab</p>
    </div> 

<script>
    // Get the element
    var elem = document.querySelector('#id0');

    //set n to the value form the previous page
    var n = 10;
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        // Create a copy of it
        var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);

        // Update the ID
        clone.id = "id" + n;

        // Inject it into the DOM
        elem.after(clone);
    }

    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```